# How to parse string to dateTime in c#?

Tags: c#, date

```
string dateString = "12/9/2014 10:09:28 AM";
DateTime dateTime;

if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"),
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dateTime))
{
   Console.WriteLine(dateTime); //"9/12/2014 10:09:28 PM";
}
```

When I do the same with "en-US" they swap to the `"12/9/2014 10:09:28 PM"`

Why did they swap day and month?

How they now where are day and where are a month?

Comment: what is the culture on your PC? I'd say that is the answer - your culture has datetime as MM/DD/YYYY, and you specified the dates should be DD/MM/YYYY (which is how dates are displayed in en-GB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simply because each culture can have its own date and time notation. The interpretation depends on your culture, just like pants mean trousers in the US but mean underwear in the UK!

In the [en-GB culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_Kingdom) dates are written in the "day month year" order and in the [en-US culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States) dates are written in the "month day, year" order.

To avoid surprises or being dependant on the machine's culture you can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or use `ParseExact`.

If you do not specify a culture, like you have in your `TryParse` call, it defaults to the current thread's culture, which is the machine's culture. You probably have `en-US` as your culture, you can check this in Control Panel > Region and Language.

Comment: But 12 can be a date and a mont

Comment: @Anatoly yes it _can_ be both, but the culture in use decides the _interpretation_.

Comment: @ but I'm not specified any culture.

Comment: @Anatoly you have not, but it defaults to the system's culture (you can change the culture for the running app if you like).

Comment: @Anatoly, if you do not specify a culture, like you have in your `TryParse` call, it defaults to the current thread's culture, which is the machine's culture.

Answer (score 7):

They swap the month and date because in the US the date format is Month/Day/Year and in Great Britain (and most of the rest of the world) the data format is Day/Month/Year.  So in the US "12/9/2014" is December, 9th 2014 and in GB it is September 12th, 2014.

That information is determined by [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

This means that you cannot interpret a date string without knowing what culture it comes from.